# How to configure prettier to have different length for html and js with vue parser?

Tags: vue-component, atom-editor, prettier

My current .prettierc file is :

```
{
        "proseWrap": "preserve",
        "overrides" : 
                [
    {
      "files": "*.vue",
      "options": {
        "semi": true,
        "printWidth": 200
      }
    }
  ]

}
```

The thing is I want 200 printWidth for html (`<template>`) and 80 printWidth for Js (`<script>`).

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported at the moment. [#5378](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5378) is the issue tracking this feature.